# Cannot implicitly convert type double to int

Tags: c#, arrays, min, strong-typing

So I have a bunch of arrays, and I'm trying to use the index of `ArrayA` for retrieving an element from `arrayB`. E.g. if I have the name `cucumber` and it's in `arrayB`, I'm trying to get the index of `cucumber` from the other array.

As shown in the code below, the last line of my code doesn't work and it tells me I cannot convert double to int.

**Edit**: I changed my code to `int index` and now my `fmin(something1, something2)` is giving me the same error...

```
    private double fmin(double[] a, int b)
    {
        double Min = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            if (Min > a[i])
                Min = a[i];
        }
        Min = Array.IndexOf(a, min);
        return Min;
    }

    int index = fmin(something1, something2);
    output = (something3[index]);
```

Comment: Since fmin returns an index, you should use int as return type. Then your code should work.

Comment: Convert your Min to int: `Convert.ToInt32(Min)` and your method return type should be `private int fmin(double[] a, int b)`

Comment: What is the datatype of the variable something2? This is a compiler error not a runtime error.

Comment: today would be a great day to get out of the habit of nmng thngs wth abbrvs. It mks it hrd 2 rd yr cd.  Call your method `MinimumValue` or some such thing that describes its purpose.

Comment: Also, this illustrates a violation of a basic principle of writing clear code: **every variable should have one purpose**. You are using `min` to mean both "the minimum value" and "the location of the minimum value", and that confusion has caused your bug.  Make a second variable that is `int` and is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to return an `int` from your function.

```
private int fmin(double[] a, int b)
{
    double Min = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        if (Min > a[i])
            Min = a[i];
    }

    return Array.IndexOf(a, Min);
}

int index = fmin(something1, something2);
output = (something3[index]);
```

Another way to solve the same problem would be to keep track of the index of the minimum value as you loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

fmin returns Min, which is type double. You're then setting index, which is type int to the return value of fmin(double). Make the variable types consistent

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as good practice, I'd recommend get used to start every algorithm with some error-case checks, to guarantee a full coverage of your inputs.

Second, as ***Eric Lippert*** stated, you must assign meaningful names to the variables, and avoid reusing them when their purpose is not the same, unless you are over-optimising some algorithm which will frequently run inside a loop with tons of iterations.

You could also make use of the power of output variables: they MUST be set before the function returns. In case of exceptions, the function is not obligated to set any values to the output variables. And so you would have a nice function which returns both `minIndex` and `minValue` from `arrayA`.

If you need a 'stable' function which never throws an exception, I've written another version implementing the "`bool TryDoSomenthing(out result)`" pattern. This function returns 'true' only in case the index computation was successful. I use this pattern widely on systems where exceptions are not ideal due to their performance hit issue in cases of multiple sequential failures.

Code:

```
// Finds the index of the lowest value in the array, considering just the 'n' first numbers.
// Throws exceptions in case of bad input parameters.
private static void GetMin(double[] a, int n, out int minIndex, out double minValue)
{
    if (a == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
    if (a.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("array 'a' contains no elements");
    if (n <= 0)
        return new ArgumentException("'n' must be greater than 0");

    minIndex = 0;
    minValue = a[0];
    if (n > a.Length)
        n = a.Length;
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        if (minValue > a[i])
            minValue = a[(minIndex = i)];
}

// Finds the index of the lowest value in the array, considering just the 'n' first numbers.
// Returns 'false' in case of bad input parameters.
private static bool TryGetMin(double[] a, int n, out int minIndex, out double minValue)
{
    if (a == null || a.Length <= 0 || n <= 0)
    {
        minIndex = -1;
        minValue = double.MinValue;
        return false;
    }

    minIndex = 0;
    minValue = a[0];
    if (n > a.Length)
        n = a.Length;
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        if (minValue > a[i])
            minValue = a[(minIndex = i)];
    return true;
}


internal static void Main()
{
    double[] arrayA = new double[] { 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0 };
    object[] arrayB = new object[] { 'x', 'y', 'z', 'w' };

    int minIndex; // index of minimum value found in 'arrayA'
    double minValue; // minimum value found in 'arrayA'
    object b; // used for storing the element of arrayB at 'minIndex'

    // With GetMin() - this code will throw an exception on bad inputs:
    GetMin(arrayA, 3, out minIndex, out minValue);
    b = arrayB[minIndex];

    // Or with TryGetMin:
    if(TryGetMin(arrayA, 3, out minIndex, out minValue))
    {
        b = arrayB[minIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        // TryGetMin() was not successful, do something about it.
        b = null;
    }

    // Or simply:
    b = TryGetMin(arrayA, 3, out minIndex, out minValue) ? arrayB[minIndex] : null;

    //...
}
```